# Development environment for .NET

Tags: .net, development-environment

I'm about to create an development environment for a little developer company(3-4 developers + some testers).
Our development platform is .NET and Oracle.

My question is how to structure the whole enviroment.How many servers do I need ? Should be one server for developers and one for testers ? I'd like to have one build server (TeamCity). 
Where to put the Subversion ? Visual Studio's would be on developers laptops.
Do I need one database for development and one extra for build server ?

What else could be helpful?

Answer (score 3):

yikes, a loaded question.

Perhaps your developers could help you plan the environment better than the helpful but random folk on SO?

Answer (score 2):

Source control can reside on an existing database server to save hardware costs, the weight of source control is negligible in this regard.  I would definitely advise having a dedicated build/integration server - we use TeamCity.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your developers are regularly out of the office, ditch the laptops. Compared to a decent developer-spec desktop workstation, they'll always cost a load more and be less capable.

Comment: I've actually found that laptop/desktop hardware is little different for development - for me IO is usually the bottleneck, so good quality HDDs are worth it.  The only time I get differences in laptop/desktop situations is graphics processing.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the DB I would say it's a matter of how much data and what type of data you have...should they have their own developer copy or do you want one big developer copy everyone is using...it's not really straight forward to structure the setup.